# ASUS X501a does not start up(fan spins, HDD does not spin, black screen)

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard, power-supply

Repairing my friend's ASUS X501a laptop. After power up, it goes into a black screen. The fan spins **a few seconds** after powering up , but HDD refuses to spin.

I have tried the following:

1. Plugged a VGA cable to my monitor. Black screen.
2. Removed HDD, battery and only use the adapter. Same problem.

Comment: Is anything displayed at all on the screen? Or does it always stay black? Try to reseat the memory modules. Does this make any difference?

Comment: A quick Google search shows that this is common... likely to be a graphics chip ball solder failure.

Comment: Always stay black. This laptop is using intergrated video. Reseating memory modules...no difference except now even the fan will not spin...